# Как вывести из одного json файла cодержимое одного обьекта на одну html cтраницу а содержимое другого обьекта на другую html страницу?

Tags: javascript

Есть два мужских товаров (рубашка) и два женских товара (платье) в файле goods.json.
Нужно чтобы при открытии страницы man.html отобразилась мужские рубашки а при открытии страницы woman.html отобразилось платья. Как реализовать это?(без использования jquery) Что добавить в мой код?

eshop.js:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function (e) {               
  loadGoods();  
});
function loadGoods() {

    $.getJSON('goods.json', function (data) {

        var out = '';
        for (var key in data){
            out+='<div class="single-goods">';
            out+='<h3>'+data[key]['name']+'</h3>';
            out+='<img src="'+data[key].image+'">';
            out+='<p>Цена: '+data[key]['cost']+'</p>';
            out+='<button class="add-to-cart" data-art="'+key+'">Купить</button>';
            out+='</div>';
        }
         document.getElementById('goods').innerHTML = out; 
         document.querySelectorAll('button.add-to-cart').forEach(function(but) {
           but.addEventListener("click",addToCart);
})
    });
}
```

goods.json:

```
{
  "Рубашка №1" : {
    "name" : "Рубашка №1",
    "cost" : 1000,
    "country" : "argentina",
    "image" : "images/1.jpg",
    "brand": "M"
  },
"Рубашка №2" : {
    "name" : "Рубашка №2",
    "cost" : 1000,
    "country" : "argentina",
    "image" : "images/1.jpg",
    "brand": "M"
  },
 "Платье №1" : {
    "name" : "Платье №1",
    "cost" : 1000,
    "country" : "brazil",
    "image" : "images/a.jpg",
     "brand": "L"
  },
 "Платье №2" : {
    "name" : "Платье №2",
    "cost" : 1000,
    "country" : "brazil",
    "image" : "images/a.jpg",
     "brand": "L"
  }
}
```

man.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
        <a href="index.html">на главную cтраницу</a>
         <div id="mini-cart"></div>
         <div id="goods"></div>
<script src="js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/eshop.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

woman.html:

```
//такой же код как и в man.html
```

Comment: я вижу вы обучались по урокам Алекса Лущенко да ? Почему бы в telegram не спросить у него лично ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

С начала в goods.json в каждый 'товар' добавить поле sex (пол по английски) со значениями: 'male', 'female' (мужской или женский)

Comment: добавил, а дальше что?

Comment: В man.html после строки: <script src="js/eshop.js"></script> вставить: <script>var sex = 'male'</script>

Comment: В woman.html после строки: <script src="js/eshop.js"></script> вставить: <script>var sex = 'female'</script>

Comment: Затем в eshop.js после строчки: for (var key in data){ вставить: if (data[key]['sex'] != sex) { continue; }

Comment: Спасибо огромное!

Comment: Удачной работы!))

Comment: спасибо и вам удачной работы!) еще хотел спросить, а если у меня например будет несколько страниц, не только мужские и женские товары, а например 4 страницы, еще хочу добавить детские товары и товары для дома.Тогда пишу например в файле goods.json в каждом 'товаре'(обьекте):
поле "category" а возле нужного обьекта пишу: male, female, kids, home. В каждом html файле пишу переменную var category, а в:
в eshop.js после строчки: for (var key in data){ 
вставляю: if (data[key]['category'] != category) { continue; } 
правильно?)

Comment: Можно и так. А у детских товаров есть пол (на мальчика, на девочку)? Если есть, то в товаре желательно добавить поле child: true/false - является ли товар деским, оставляя при этом не тронутым поле sex